# Setting DATEFIRST to 6

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date-format

I would like to set `FIRSTDATE` to 6 (ie: saturday), i have read that to change it parmanently i could set the default language of the login to one of an existing language from the `sys.syslanguages` and alter the login of the user like:

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER LOGIN [some_user] WITH DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [Français]
GO
```

But:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.syslanguages;
```

i get many languages, but no one has the `DATEFIRST` set to 6 (they are all set to 1 or 7).

Question:

Can i add another language based on an existing one, and set de field `datefirst` to 6 ?

Can i modify an existing syslanguage ?

All what i want, is te set it to 6 parmanently, because i need it to get the right week number.

Thank you for help !

Answer (score 2):

**Can i add another language based on an existing one, and set de field datefirst to 6 ?
Can i modify an existing syslanguage ?**

You cannot modify sys.language in 2005 and up.

**All what i want, is te set it to 6 parmanently, because i need it to get the right week number.**

Is there any specific reason to do this at sql server level ? Why cant this be done at the application level ?

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=62891 has a method to do it using registry changes, but be CAUTIOUS of doing it without proper testing !!

**Edit: Added my comment in answer:**

How about using SET DATEFIRST N (where N = 1 through 7 and 7 is default). Ref: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259210(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Yes, because i want to use the `select datepart(wk,datetime)` to get the week number using views, for this i have to change the the datefirst to 6 to get the right week number, but the `set datefirst` command can't nether be used inside function, nore inside views

Comment: How about using SET DATEFIRST N (where N = 1 through 7 and 7 is default). Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259210(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: I believe @Kin has your answer in his comment. For the 2008 link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598%28v=sql.100%29.aspx